# How to monitor or do vacuum without stop all?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have postgres9.1

I try to run full vacuum on a specific table , but it run for more than 5 hours.
I stop all process against this table and i cannot have the process down any longer.

Is there a way to run vacuum in background?
Is there a way to monitor vacuum?

Comment: Answer updated with a bit more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VACUUM FULL` takes an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, then rewrites the whole table. This will take a long time for a large table, especially since it must also rebuild all indexes. You haven't said anything about the table size or the server's I/O subsystem so it's hard to say if 5 hours is unexpected or not.

You shouldn't generally need to use `VACUUM FULL`. Just use ordinary `VACUUM` - and turn autovacuum up so it works harder if you need to do a manual `VACUUM` more than very occasionally. It is safe to cancel the `VACUUM FULL`; doing so will undo all it's work, though.

You generally only need to run `VACUUM FULL` if you're trying to recover from severe table bloat caused by a long-running `<IDLE> in transaction` connection, an abaondoned prepared transaction, insufficiently aggressive autovacuum, etc. If you can't afford the downtime required for this you can look into [`pg_reorg`](http://reorg.projects.pgfoundry.org/pg_reorg.html) as an online, reduced-locking alternative.